# R - "level.plot" function from biomod2 removed in latest versions, any alternative?

Tags: r, plot, deprecated, modeling, terra

There is a function in the biomod2 package version 3.5.1 called level.plot(). When I use a more recent biomod2 version (eg. 4.2-3) I can not find such a function and after searching in the biomod2 documentation I haven't been lucky finding an alternative for it nor why this function has been removed.
What the function used to do was plot the occurrence and absence data of a species on a map, so that I just needed to have a dataframe with the geographical coordinates of the presences/absences, and another column to specify if each row is a presence (1) or absence (0).
So I would like to know if biomod2 still has this functionality somewhere or if maybe it is accomplished with other associated packages such as "terra".
Thank you!